# (SEO + htaccess) Page-list with pagination and page-detail

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination, seo

i've a problem with SEO - PHP.

I have 2 pages: a news list page and a news detail page.

But, on the SEO point-view, how can I distinguish those two pages in URL ?

At the moment, I'm using those URLs:

- www.site.com/it/news/page-1/ - www.site.com/it/news/page-2/ ... 
  (news list with pagination)
- www.site.com/it/news/title-news-detail/
  (news detail)

My file .htaccess code:

```
# first parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
#

# second parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
#

# third parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&param=$3 [L]
```

My problem is to read the third parameter, because I don't know if this is the page number or the news title..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
# ignore files and directories from all rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# first parameter
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

# second parameter with pagination
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page-(\d+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

# second parameter with title
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]

# third parameter
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&param=$3 [L,QSA]
```